# CANNOT GRANT CREATE VIEW ON SCHEMA

Tags: postgresql, view, sql-grant

I have a user in a database who only can select datas on all tables. I want to alow him to create views and not tables.
Is it possible to grant to a specific user privileges for only creating views in a database schema?

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in PostgreSQL at time of writing, no. The `CREATE` right in a schema lets them create any object type. There's no way to limit what objects they can create - functions, operators, operator classes, tables, views, etc.

You could implement an executor hook to enforce these kinds of rules, but you'll have to do it as a loadable module written in C. `ProcessUtility_hook` is probably the hook you want. There will be a significant learning curve to this approach, as you'll need to understand how PostgreSQL's statements are described in their internal parsed form.

Comment: IMHO it would also be needed to restrict the view-only user to a separate "scratch only" schema. (and put this schema first in the users search_path)