# Grant CREATE VIEW privileges in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

is it possible to just grand CREATE VIEW privileges on a particular schema in postgres? I have a user that wants to creates views but I don't necessarily want to give him CREATE privileges on the database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CANNOT GRANT CREATE VIEW ON SCHEMA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811683/cannot-grant-create-view-on-schema)

Comment: That's from 5 years ago, maybe things have changed

Comment: Which PostgreSQL version do you use?

Comment: @RaymondNijland  I use the version 9.5

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.5 looks to support `GRANT { { CREATE | USAGE } [, ...] | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON SCHEMA schema_name [, ...]
    TO role_specification [, ...] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]` looking into the BNF codes.  source https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-grant.html .. So it looks like you can give CREATE PRIVILEGES on a SCHEMA.